# How can I prove $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{a.n-(a-1)}{n!}=e$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can I prove this

> $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{a*n-(a-1)}{n!}=e$$
>   When $a$ is any real number

Comment: What does $a.n$ represent?What have you done?

Comment: Also fun to consider, for natural numbers $k$: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n^k}{n!}$.

Comment: Yes, this is a good question, the fun how you know the function of the power of $e$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n}{n!}=\frac{0}{0!}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n+1}{(n+1)!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}=e
$$
And therefore:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{an-(a-1)}{n!}=a\cdot\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n}{n!}-(a-1)\cdot\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}=ae-(a-1)e=e
$$